# I'd like to connect to mysql and ionic2

Tags: mysql, node.js, ionic2

I use the node.js server and the mysql database.

I tried to connect to mysql and ionic2, 
but it was very difficult to connect to mysql and ionic2.

How do I have to do?
or is there any site to see?

please, let me know about this.

Comment: you should be sending requests to nodejs server api.. not sure what you mean by connecting ionic 2 with mysql..are you talking about client side db?

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the help center and edit your question to provide a specific problem. Your question looks off topic to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is, you need to develop **Restful API** where it interacts with the MySQL Database and use that API to fetch and put data (CRUD) from your Ionic2 app.

Comment: yeah the client side is right. thank you so much : )

Comment: Sampath, thank you so much : ) My colleague says " Sampath's answer is very useful to solve the problem!!

Comment: It's pleasure :)